# Force image orientation angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this odd behavior when I upload an image and if this image size has more height than with I get the image rotated 90 degrees.

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melnikovkolya/a2ew3yhf/2/) that's using [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) and this is the [image](http://www.asesoriait.net/images/IMG_1854.JPG) that I'm uploading

the code of the ngDmgCrop it's pretty standard:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngImgCrop'])
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myImage='';
    $scope.myCroppedImage='';

    var handleFileSelect=function(evt) {
      var file=evt.currentTarget.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.myImage=evt.target.result;
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };
    angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput')).on('change',handleFileSelect);
  });
```

how can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to parse the exif data in the image header, examine the Orientation tag, and rotate accordingly.

I just solved the same problem with this library: [**Javascript Load Image**](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

In your **app.js**

```
  var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {

      var target  = evt.dataTransfer || evt.target;
      var file    = target && target.files && target.files[0];
      var options = {canvas:true};

      var displayImg = function(img) {
        $scope.$apply(function($scope){
          $scope.myImage=img.toDataURL();
        });
      }

      loadImage.parseMetaData(file, function (data) {
        if (data.exif) {
          options.orientation = data.exif.get('Orientation');
        }
        loadImage(file, displayImg, options );
      });

  };
```

Demo : [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wuAMAsHZcfNnBmiEhYsK?p=preview)

Cheers.