# How to prevent image portrait image flip on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have problem on mobile devices phone just flip portrait images...

I am using Angular 2...

Here is the code:

```
<input type="file" name="file" accept="image/*"
 (change)="handleInputChange($event)" multiple>
```

And function:

```
handleInputChange(e) {
        var files = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files : e.target.files;
        var pattern = /image-*/;

        let joined = this.toArray(this._sharedService.filesProduct).concat(this.toArray(files));
        this._sharedService.filesProduct = joined;

        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            this.loaded = false;

            reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
            reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        }

    }
```

I think it is some problem with html part, not sure why it flipping portrait image on phones.

Comment: Are you uploading JPG?  Some JPG have rotation encoded into their metadata.

Comment: I think it is JPG... Because it is images captured by phone camera...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force image orientation angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27204309/force-image-orientation-angularjs)

Comment: It is not I need to prevent image flipping on phone not to crop a picture.

Comment: Read the answer to that question.  You need to parse EXIF data and see if the file is rotated by metadata or not.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I need somehow to prevent EXIF data to influence on picture rotation.

Comment: Did you read the first and only answer to that linked question?  It provides a way to do it.

Comment: Could you show me an example how to do that for Angular 2? on my code above...

Answer (score 0):

Using the default application (from [Angular's QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)) that is built whenever you run `ng new my-app` with Angular, along with this EXIF library: [exif-js](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js).  Here is an example of how to read EXIF data from a JPG:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {EXIF} from 'exif-js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
    handleInputChange(e) {
        const files = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files : e.target.files,
              fr = new FileReader();
        fr.addEventListener('load', () => {
            const data = fr.result;
            const exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(fr.result);
            console.log(exif);
        });
        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(files[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you add  exif-js to angular cli project?

Comment: @Vladimir Go to the root of your application and run [`npm i --save exif-js`](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js#install).

Comment: @Vladimir Define "not working", have you done any debugging on this problem?

Comment: Yes here is the error: `Cannot find module 'exif-js'`